# Invalid index path for use with UITableView when selecting rows beyond a certain number

Tags: xcode, uitableview

```
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:   (NSInteger)section
{
return @"Substitutes";
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

int cnt=[subArray count];
return [subArray count];
}

- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
NSArray *visible = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

NSIndexPath *indexpath = (NSIndexPath*)[visible objectAtIndex:0];


if ((selectedIndexPath != nil) && (selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row)){


    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *subtitle =[[subArray objectAtIndex:row] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSString *subDet =[[subDetArray objectAtIndex:row] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    int height =  [self heightOfCellWithTitle:subtitle andSubtitle:subDet];
    return(height < CONST_Cell_height ? CONST_Cell_height : height);


}

return 40.0;
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
if ((selectedIndexPath != nil) && (selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row)){
    cell = [self CreateMultilinesCell:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text=[[subArray objectAtIndex:row] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text =[[subDetArray objectAtIndex:row] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    return cell;        
} else {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.textLabel.text=[[subArray objectAtIndex:row] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text =[[subDetArray objectAtIndex:row] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    return cell; 
 }

}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (selectedIndexPath == indexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = nil;
    [table reloadData];
} else {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    //cell.textLabel.text=@"test";
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text =@"det Test";
    [table reloadData];
}
 [self.table deselectRowAtIndexPath : indexPath animated : NO];
 [tableView beginUpdates];
 [tableView endUpdates];

}
```

i implemented table view using above code.when i selecting  row no. 26 v or more it 
expands on selection but doesn't contract on next click.& gives me error on scroll

NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.'

code work smoothly for 25 rows. where i went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got it finaly.:) selectedIndexpath  gives garbage. i replace it by self.selectedIndexpath.
i didnt get why it do so on record no. 25 onwards.But this worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag-1 inSection:0];

CGRect rectOfCellInTableView = [objTableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

CGRect rectOfCellInSuperview = [objTableView convertRect:rectOfCellInTableView toView:[objTableView superview]];
```